# NServicebus saga performance

Tags: nservicebus, saga

I have a trouble with NSB saga performance. We have one single saga that orchestrate long running session. Saga sends a lot of messages to different processors and than gets its replies.
I see that sagas queue contains tons of incoming messages. Each messages processing is very fast, but there is a delay between handling next message. Here is a part of log file:

```
16:26:42 [14][DEBUG] Finished handling message.  
16:26:46 [15][DEBUG] ChildContainerBehavior  
16:26:46 [15][DEBUG] MessageHandlingLoggingBehavior  
16:26:46 [15][DEBUG] Received message with ID 28b285ce-3b77-4a69-a13a-a3bf009717fd from sender xxxHost@PROCESSOR01
```

We see a 4 seconds delay. That is very slow. Please help, what is wrong with my saga?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a monolithic saga, you will have some contention on the state record that backs the saga in storage.  You will want to consider breaking up your endpoint or redesigning how you gather the information.  Check out this [Routing Slip](https://github.com/jbogard/NServiceBus.MessageRouting) implementation.

Comment: Saga data is not very large. I think that 2 seconds is very slow for persisting saga data

Comment: Agreed, the size may not be the factor, but locking on that row could be a factor.

Comment: I have only one saga instance, so this is very strange